# jQuery chosen(chzn) update options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select elements, where 1 of them should be searchable and the other not. It's important that the first select element does not have any class, since chzn chould be applied to all  tags.

HTML

```
<select>
 <option>Option 1</option>
</select>

<select class="searchable">
 <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$("select").chosen({ disable_search: true, create_option: true, persistent_create_option: true, skip_no_results: true, width: "100%" }); 
$("select.searchable").chosen({ disable_search: false });
```

What am i doing wrong? the second row in my js script isn't overriding the first row.

Comment: Have you tried adding a class unsearchable to the first select? I guess it doesn't override your first function (and it's certainly not a good practice, by the way).

Comment: "It's important that the first select element does not have any class"

as mentioned, i'm trying not to use any class for the first select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not overriding, you are trying to create chosen again. So it doesn't work becouse you have to kill original chosen first and then recreate. I would recommend using not() when creating chosen on elements.

```
 $("select").not(".searchable").chosen({ disable_search: true, create_option: true, persistent_create_option: true, skip_no_results: true, width: "100%" });
 $("select.searchable").chosen({ disable_search: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

As of v1.0 of `chosen`, you can now just update the `Select` and invoke and update trigger using:

```
$("<chosen-select>").trigger("chosen:updated")
```